# How to use normal mode commands in ex mode?

Tags: normal-mode, ex-mode

When I start vi/vim as `ex`, I can use the `-c` option to provide the set of *ex* commands to apply to a file:

```
echo Yes | ex -sc 's/Y/y/|%p|q!' /dev/stdin
yes
```

But how can I use *normal mode* commands like the `~` (switch case command) with `ex`?

Comment: If you want to switch case you could use [`:h g~`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#g%7e) (e.g. `:norm! g~2W`) and not use visual mode.

Comment: Thanks, @statox. Indeed running _normal_ mode command is what I was looking for. However, could you post an answer with the full command? I tried a couple of variations around `echo 'Élève' | ex -sc ':norm! g~|%p|q!' /dev/stdin` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a comment by @statox, I found a solution:

```
echo 'Élève' | ex -sc 'norm! g~w' -c '%p|q!' /dev/stdin
éLÈVE
```

The [`norm`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal) command allows executing Normal mode commands.
And I had to use two `-c` option since, after `norm`, the rest of the line is considered part of the normal-mode command to execute.

Comment: Yup I couldn't answer your comment in time but that's what I meant :) Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted when you can so that the question has an answer. Also for this kind of manipulation, I would rather use `sed` or `perl` substitution command rather than vim.

Comment: There are some situations where, as far as I know, ex can be easier than sed. For instance, for removing a specific tag that spread across multiple lines. The ex commands '/id="todelete"' and 'dat' would delete the tag wit todelete id regardless of how many lines the tag takes.